# Cannot find package when deploy to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, app-engine-flexible, gopath

I can not deploy my golang application (with [echo](https://github.com/labstack/echo) framework) on App Engine.

I have some kind of error like:

```
...
Step #0: main.go:4:2: cannot find package "FBackend/router" in any of:
Step #0: /usr/local/go/src/FBackend/router (from $GOROOT) 
Step #0: /workspace/_gopath/src/FBackend/router (from $GOPATH) 
Finished 
Step #0 ERROR 
ERROR: build step 0 "..." failed: exit status 1
```

In project I have file three like this:

```
FBackend
    ...
    |___router
    |   |____router.go
    ...
    |
    |___main.go
```

On localhost all works fine

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message, you should set one of the paths to the "src" folder.

They should be able to find "FBackend/router" in "/usr/local/go/src/" since it's there.

I can understand how it can't find "FBackend/router" in "/usr/local/go/src/FBackend/router" cause you probably don't have "/usr/local/go/src/FBackend/router/FBackend/router" setup.